# How to retain the data submitted by two buttons using php?

Tags: php

How can I retain the data inside a table cells submitted by two buttons using php?
**Here's the output:**
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8hDy.jpg)

**This is the result I wanted** *(Note: Image below is just edited using image editor)*:
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGxJ1.jpg)

This is the code I used:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample </title>
</head>
<body>

<table border = "1" align = "center" cellpadding = "10" >
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<tr>
<td>Output1 : 
  <?php 
     if (isset($_POST['run1'])) {
     echo "<b>" .$_POST['input1']. "</b>"; 
     }  
  ?> 
 /td>

<td>Output2 : 
<?php 
   if (isset($_POST['run2'])) {
     echo "<b>" .$_POST['input2']. "</b>"; 
   }
?>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type = "text" name = "input1" value = "Type here..."></td>
<td><input type = "text" name = "input2" value = "Type here..."></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align = "center"><input type = "submit" name = "run1" value = "Button 1"></td>
<td align = "center"><input type = "submit" name = "run2" value = "Button 2"> </td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe using $_SESSION to save data even if the Page reloads

Comment: save it on any persistence store: session, cookie, database, so forth

Comment: I already tried $_SESSION but I still get same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply check for the other key name:

```
 <?php 
     if(!empty($_POST['input1'])) {
        echo "<b>" .$_POST['input1']. "</b>"; 
     }  
  ?>
```

then the other would be:

```
 <?php 
     if(!empty($_POST['input2'])) {
        echo "<b>" .$_POST['input2']. "</b>"; 
     }  
  ?>
```

Don't check if the button is set, rather if the content of the input is filled. You only need to persist the data using the session if you intend to use the content past this page, but from your example, you are not appearing to need that.

Also, you should probably use `htmlspecialchars()` as in:

```
echo "<b>" .htmlspecialchars($_POST['input2']). "</b>";
```

---

**EDIT:** Since you actually want to persist the data, a session is required:

```
<?php
# Start session (don't hide warnings)
session_start();
# Check if content being submitted
if(!empty($_POST['input1']))
    $_SESSION['input1'] = $_POST['input1'];
if(!empty($_POST['input2']))
    $_SESSION['input2'] = $_POST['input2'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <table border = "1" align = "center" cellpadding = "10" >
        <tr>
            <td>Output1 : 
                <?php 
                if(!empty($_SESSION['input1']))
                    echo "<b>" .htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['input1']). "</b>";
                ?> 
            </td>
            <td>Output2 : 
                <?php 
                if(!empty($_SESSION['input2']))
                    echo "<b>" .htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['input2']). "</b>";
                ?> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type = "text" name = "input1" value = "Type here...">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type = "text" name = "input2" value = "Type here...">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align = "center"><input type = "submit" name = "run1" value = "Button 1">
            </td>
            <td align = "center">
                <input type = "submit" name = "run2" value = "Button 2">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But I still got the same problem, When I type "Hello 1" in the first input box then click Button 1 it appears on the first column (output 1) But when I type on the second input box "Hello 2" and hit Button 2 there's an output on second column (output 2) but the output 1 in the first column was gone? Thanks, appreciates your help.

Comment: Are you trying to load them at the same time or have the user do one, submit, do the other, then submit again and have both show? If that is the case, you have to use session to persist the data.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do :P
1. Input on first textbox then hit button 1, appear on the top table cell (column 1)
2. Input again on the second textbox then hit button 2, then appear on the top table cell again (column 2) Thanks!

Comment: Then yes, if you want to be able to click the submit buttons at separate times, then you need to save to session, but you need to do it above your html is output to the page.

Comment: BTW, is there a way to clear the data recorded in my inputbox? I mean when I reload the page all data are cleared again? Here's the image: https://imgur.com/6nU9w8d Thanks in advanced again :)

Comment: Those look like what your browser is saving for quick retrieval. You might be able to clear that by clearing all your browser cache/data.

Comment: That being said, you can clear the session by using `unset($_SESSION['input1']);`, but that looks like your browser is recalling through cache.

Comment: Thanks again :) Is there a way to avoid it? I mean an alternative beside from input box? Or a code to clear the cache like: clearstatcache(); But this does not work for me :P Thanks!

Comment: That is a browser thing, the best you can do is add `autocomplete="off"`to the input tag, but some browsers ignore that setting. So for example the input would look like `<input type="text" name="input2" value="Type here..." autocomplete="off" />`

Comment: Finally, if you want to persist data from page to page, you just need to add `session_start();` to the top of each page. That will allow you to both access previously set values and set new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ! :)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample </title>
</head>
<body>

<table border = "1" align = "center" cellpadding = "10" >
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

<tr>
<td>Output1 : 
  <?php 

  @session_start();


     if (!empty($_POST['input1'])) {

         $_SESSION["input1"] = $_POST['input1'];
         }

     echo "<b>" .$_SESSION["input1"]. "</b>"; 

  ?> 
 </td>

<td>Output2 : 
<?php 
   if (!empty($_POST['input2'])) {
       $_SESSION["input2"] = $_POST['input2'];
       }
     echo "<b>" .$_SESSION["input2"]. "</b>"; 

?>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type = "text" name = "input1" placeholder = "Type here..."></td>
<td><input type = "text" name = "input2" placeholder = "Type here..."></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align = "center"><input type = "submit" name = "run1" value = "Button 1"></td>
<td align = "center"><input type = "submit" name = "run2" value = "Button 2"> </td>
</tr>

</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['inputs'])){ //check weather $_SESSION['inputs'] exist or not. define if not exist like below.
        $_SESSION['inputs'] = array('','');
    }
    if (isset($_POST['run1'])) { //on click first button assign first input's value to $_SESSION['input'][0];
        $_SESSION["inputs"][0] = $_POST['input1'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['run2'])) {//on click second button assign first input's value to $_SESSION['input'][1];
        $_SESSION["inputs"][1] = $_POST['input2'];
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <table border = "1" align = "center" cellpadding = "10" >
                <tr>
                    <td>Output1 : <b><?php echo $_SESSION['inputs'][0]; ?></b></td>
                    <td>Output2 : <b><?php echo $_SESSION['inputs'][1]; ?></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type = "text" name = "input1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['inputs'][0]; ?>" placeholder = "Type here..."></td>
                    <td><input type = "text" name = "input2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['inputs'][1]; ?>" placeholder = "Type here..."></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align = "center"><input type = "submit" name = "run1" value = "Button 1"></td>
                    <td align = "center"><input type = "submit" name = "run2" value = "Button 2"> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you for giving another solution :)